# How to search folders and reconfigure any matching paths as output through PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm a newbie in windows scripting, so bear with me.

I want to find "test" folder from multiple folders. Such as

Search test folders from multiple paths:

```
/rbl.com/mailroot/test
/pml.com/mailroot/test
/pax.com/mailroot/
```

Want to get output like that:

```
test@rbl.com
test@pml.com
```

I have run this command to get results `dir /S test > c:\results.txt`

Output:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 4A9E-06D4

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Mail Servers\Mail Enable\Postoffices\rbl.com\MAILROOT

08/05/2016  12:36 AM    <DIR>          test
       0 File(s)              0 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Mail Servers\Mail Enable\Postoffices\pml.com\MAILROOT

08/05/2016  12:36 AM    <DIR>          test
       0 File(s)              0 bytes
```

But how to extract the information like:

```
test@rbl.com
test@pml.com
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using (see `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
 ls test -Directory -Recurse | % { "$($_.Name)@$($_.Parent.Parent.Name)" }
```

It searches your folders recursively for test folders, then prints out the folder's parent, its parent, and the folder's name as you want it formatted.

Comment: The other way around. `"{0}@{1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Parent.Parent.Name`

Comment: I have run command `ls test -Directory -Recurse | % { "$($_.Parent.Parent.Name)@$($_.Name)" }` it shows output like this:


**airportdirectcabs.com@test**
**aoryxcarrental.ae@test**

Comment: It works i have run same command  through this way `ls test -Directory -Recurse | % { "$($_.Name)@$($_.Parent.Parent.Name)" }`

Comment: ah my bad, I changed to answer accordingly for clarity